# Improvement on len(sentence.split()) for finding the number of words in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

The standard approach to couting the number of words in a sentence in python seems to be to use `len(sentence.split(<separator character(s)>))`. However this has always struck me as very inefficient as you are creating an entire list just to count the number of separator characters not preceded by another separator character.

I know it would be fairly simple to write a function to do the same job but

a) this is a bit clunky to do wherever you need to do it and

b) because the function would be written in python rather than an in-built C function it probably wouldn't be much more efficient either.

So anyone think of an efficient one-liner to take the place of `len(string.split())`?

edit:
To clarify string.count(" ") + 1 does not fulfil the same purpose as len(string.split(" ")) count counts leading, trailing and repeated character so it is not a good method for counting the number of words as it only works in the idealised case where the string starts with a word, ends with a word and has no double spaces

Comment: `len(string.split())` **is** a one-liner. You could also use `string.count(sep)`.

Comment: Also, speaking of efficiency, it is *NEVER* a good idea to assume efficiency based on how you imagine the function would work. There may be all kinds of optimisations, so that the only way to tell if method A is faster than method B is through rigid benchmarking.

Comment: Silly question, but why would you want to count the number words, but not use the words? Aren't you eventually going to need a list of the words for some purpose? Separate the split from the counting.

Comment: @MattDMo *string.count(sep)* might work but what it sep == ' ' and some of the words are separated by two (or more) spaces?

Comment: @Stuart `string.count(" ")` would only work properly if it was a "standard" sentence with a single space between words. That was kind of my point (although I probably could have expressed it a little more directly) - `len(string.split())` is the best way of going about counting words.

Comment: @MattDMo Completely agree that *len(string.split())* is the way to go. If anyone can write something in pure Python that's faster than that then I would be amazed

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation.

Comment: @navneethc it's more a curiosity than a true optimisation. I'm sure there are cases where it would be significant but in my case it's just generally because I hate doing anything I known is really inefficient even if it isn't significant to the overall runtime of the program

Comment: @MattDMo the goal is a more efficient version and no string.count(sep) doesn't work as any double spaces will cause the count to be wrong

Comment: @MMZK1526 I'm not basing it on how I assume the function works I'm basing it one what the function returns. .split returns a list of strings, that cannot be an efficient method of counting the number of separators not preceded by another separator

Comment: @AdamLadd how do you know *"that cannot be an efficient method"*? Look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/stringlib/split.h). It's implemented in C using efficient algorithms (depending on whether there is an argument or not) and internal data structures that have been optimized over the last 30+ years. How else would *you* do it? Lists are one of the core Python data structures - they're as fast as anything else in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of time, `len(string.split())` would be hard if not impossible to beat. But if space is a concern it might be possible to improve.

Let's start by taking a looking at the built in [split method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L53)

```
i = j = 0;
while (maxcount-- > 0) {
    while (i < str_len && STRINGLIB_ISSPACE(str[i]))
        i++;
    if (i == str_len) break;
    j = i; i++;
    while (i < str_len && !STRINGLIB_ISSPACE(str[i]))
        i++;
#if !STRINGLIB_MUTABLE
    if (j == 0 && i == str_len && STRINGLIB_CHECK_EXACT(str_obj)) {
        /* No whitespace in str_obj, so just use it as list[0] */
        Py_INCREF(str_obj);
        PyList_SET_ITEM(list, 0, (PyObject *)str_obj);
        count++;
        break;
    }
#endif
    SPLIT_ADD(str, j, i);
}
```

maxcount: is a parameter, it can limit the string to only be split *x* number of times. If not set there is no limit.

The function loops over the string looking for whitespace and splits the words into a list accordingly. The time complexity would be O(n) and the space complexity would also be O(n) as it would require auxiliary space for a List the size of the string.

An improvement in space but not time in my testing could be done by writing a function that loops over the string counting spaces. My function looked like this:

```
def count_words(s):
    space_prev = True
    word_count = 0
    index = 0

    while index < len(s):
        if s[index] == ' ' and not space_prev:
            word_count += 1
            space_prev = True
        elif space_prev and s[index] != ' ':
            space_prev = False
        index += 1

    if space_prev:
        return word_count

    return word_count + 1
```

This function has a time complexity of O(n) and space complexity of O(1). Although by being written in Python it runs slower than the builtin C function despite having the same algorithmic runtime and saving space.

Here's my test timings (first number is time, second is space):

```
String with 69 words:
---------------------
builtin: 0.0009369159999999994, 11.567104 mb
count_words: 0.006606459, 11.583488 mb

String with 101 words:
----------------------
builtin: 0.0009850830000000012, 11.517952 mb
count_words: 0.009976667000000002, 11.567104 mb

String with 1,010 words:
------------------------
builtin: 0.007890958999999996, 11.632640 mb
count_words: 0.101723584, 11.567104 mb

String with 10,100 words:
-------------------------
builtin: 0.044037375, 11.911168 mb
count_words: 1.026273333, 11.747328 mb
```

In the end the space was quite negligible as well. So unless you have a huge amount of words to count it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was overrating the overhead of creating a list of strings and underrating C's advantage of python. Looks like for all practical purposes the standard implementation is going to be superior.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in a comment, you can use

```py
string.count(" ") + 1
```

which is, according to a quick test I just did, faster. You will, however, quickly run into problems if there are consecutive spaces (`"I  am"` will say 3 words) or the string has leading or trailing spaces (`" I am "` would be 4 words). Long story short, `split()` is optimized to accurately separate the words, so it will deal with a lot of headaches by itself, even if it is slower.

### Speed testing

Here is some benchmarking:

```py
from timeit import timeit

string = 'During a combat medical training class, the topic was blast injuries. At one point, our very intimidating instructor pointed at me and said, “There’s been a jeep explosion. What would you do if you came upon an injured man with a steering wheel embedded in his chest?” Nervous and unsure, I blurted out, “Drive him to the hospital?” For some reason, the rest of the room found this hilarious.'

def builtin_split():
    return len(string.split())

def builtin_count():
    return string.count(" ") + 1

def improved_count():
    # Takes care of leading, trailing and double spaces.
    # Doesn't take care of triple and longer
    stripped_string = string.strip()
    return stripped_string.strip().count(" ") + 1 - stripped_string.count("  ")

def custom_implementation():
    # Only uses spaces as separators
    s = string.strip()
    length = len(s)
    words = 0
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        while i < length and s[i] != " ":
            i += 1
        while i < length and s[i] == " ":
            i += 1
        words += 1
    
    return words


print("split:" ,timeit(builtin_split))
print("count:", timeit(builtin_count))
print("improved count:", timeit(improved_count))
print("custom implementation:", timeit(custom_implementation))
```

Output:

```
split: 4.68428400799985
count: 1.250697097000284
improved count: 2.0560090240001045
custom implementation: 123.93436312599988
```

Using just the simple `count` is around 3.5x faster, but as mentioned, unreliable. When you improve `count` to take care of trailing and leading spaces, as well as double spaces, it is still more than 2x faster than using `split`. That would probably cover the vast majority of errors of `count`, but would still fail to get the correct result on a string with triple or more spaces (`"I   am"`). I would say that is generally still nowhere near worth the tiny performance boost. As expected, a custom implementation in Python is immeasurably slower.

Comment: @FilipMüller I concur. Your suggestion **is** faster according to my benchmark. With a sentence comprised of 180 characters and 31 words it's almost 4 times faster than the split technique. But, as has been previously stated, it's potentially not as robust as you might hope